If the .NET 6 Host Bundle is already installed, will my trying to install it cause any issues?
I'm trying to get an ASP.NET MVC app deployed to a server running IIS 10. I came across this post How do I deploy .NET 6 web app to IIS 10?, which I've followed. I then read this Microsoft articles Host ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS and The .NET Core Hosting Bundle, which eventually led me the host bundle for .NET 6.
However, before I download and install the host bundle for .NET 6, I'd like to know what may happen if it is already installed and I try to install it again? I've not found anything called ".NET 6 Hosting Bundle" in Programs. And I have found the Microsoft .NET SDK 6.0.422 installed on that Windows Server. Is the .NET 6 Hosting Bundle included with the SDK?

In my experience major versions of frameworks/hosting bundles etc will co-exist with other versions and refuse to install if exact version is already installed(theres a repair option for that). I doubt you need both the SDK and hosting bundle - for production servers the bundle is preferred as it contains everything you need. I suspect the SDK wont register itself with IIS (and its huge) whereas the hosting bundle is relatively small and will prepare IIS for you.  You should ask this over on superuser.com if you want a proper answer. Voting to close as off topic.

I don't believe it is installed with the SDK.  (The SDK isn't necessary on the server unless you develop there, and you don't need the hosting bundle on the development machine, only the SDK.)  I believe .NET and Hosting Bundle versions install side-by-side, but not real sure as I usually uninstall older versions before installing new.

both SDK and Hosting bundle include the .NET run-time.  You can exclude that from hosting bundle install by passing an argument, but it will handle it all gracefully.   The only reason to exclude the .NET Core run-time install would be if you publish self-contained and wanted to keep the disk space.

if it helps, it should be listed in Apps & Features as "Microsoft .NET version# - Windows Server Hosting"

According to your scenario and description, reinstalling the .NET 6 Hosting Bundle is usually safe. It won't cause issues if it's already installed and the process will likely just inform you that it's already present. The Hosting Bundle (for IIS deployment) is separate from the .NET SDK (for development), but often included with it. You can check for the Bundle's presence using the command prompt or IIS Manager. If the .NET SDK is installed (especially a recent version), the Hosting Bundle is likely there as well, so you can proceed with deploying your ASP.NET MVC app to IIS.

@browsermator looking at Apps & Features on the server, I see Microsoft .NET 7.0.19 - Windows Server Hosting. So, that's for .NET 7. Will that work for .NET 6?

Don't know for sure.  Seemed like .NET 7 in general was pretty buggy, but the hosting bit is outside of .NET so...  basically if the site is working now without throwing some nasty server errors you are good to go.  I'd tend to want the host bundle and .net run-time versions to match, though.  If you want to upgrade, .NET 8 is the Long Term Support version.

Now that I take a look, .NET 7 is already out of support, so .NET 6 or .NET 8 would be better: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core
